# How to force list context for logical or operator

Tags: perl

I have a script that allows user to enter through either command line argument or stdin so I did:

```
my @expr = @ARGV || <STDIN>;
```

This did not work as expected. I only got some numbers like 1. I had to use the version below:

```
my @expr = @ARGV;
if (!@expr) {
  @expr = <STDIN>;
}
```

Why is this happening? How to make the first version to work (if possible)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `||` operator needs its LHS in scalar context. The same expression can't be both list and scalar at the same time.

The neatest way to do that would be to use the `? :` ternary operator:

```
my @expr = @ARGV ? @ARGV : <STDIN>;
```

This way, the first occurence of `@ARGV` is scalar and thus tests for non-empty, but the second is in list context so yields its actual items.